# Import a CSV and after that get AD group infos out of one column

Tags: powershell, active-directory, import-csv

I use a CSV file where I find the accumulated security infos of file-server-folders.

CSV looks like that:

```
Pfad;Ordnerebene;Berechtigungsgruppe_Domaene;Berechtigungsgruppe;Rechteart;Recht
X:\;0;VORDEFINIERT;Administrators;Allowed;CHANGE
X:\;0;company;AdminsEupl;Allowed;CHANGE
X:\;0;company;EUPL.EDV;Allowed;CHANGE
X:\;0;;;Allowed;CHANGE
X:\backup;1;company;AdminsEupl;Allowed;CHANGE
```

I want to question active directory about details (owner, members, managedby, etc.) from "Berechtigungsgruppe" and export this details into another CSV.

Code is this:

```bsh
$dateipfad = "<pathtomyfile>"
Import-Csv $dateipfad -Encoding Unicode -Delimiter ";"| foreach {
    $a = ($_.Pfad)
    $b = ($_.Ordnerebene)
    $c = ($_.Berechtigungsgruppe_domaene)
    $d = ($_.Berechtigungsgruppe)
    $e = ($_.Rechteart)
    $f = ($_.Recht)
    $g =  '*' + $d + '*'
}

$Array = Get-ADGroup -Filter {name -like '$g'} |
         Select-Object -Unique -ExpandProperty Name
$Liste = foreach ($element in $Array) {
    Get-ADGroup $element -Properties managedby | 
        Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $element | 
        Get-Aduser -Properties name, DisplayName, Mail | 
        Select-Object name, DisplayName, Mail,
            @{Name='Group';Expression={$element}}, managedby
}
$Liste
$Liste | Export-Csv -Path o:\powershell\GruppenMitglieder.csv -Append -Encoding Unicode -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ';'
```

but all I got in the resulting CSV is: `ÿþ`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `ÿþ` is [Byte Order Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). Which application did you try to open the result file with?

Comment: i use excel to open the resulting csv - there is nothing else in the file, just the bom

Comment: According to [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_other-mso_2010/opening-csv-file-with-utf16-encoding-in-excel-2010/ed522cb9-e88d-4b82-b88e-a2d4bd99f874) there appears to be a bug in Excel importing UTF-16-encoded CSVs.

Comment: The problem isnt any bug, it is that those 3 parts in my ps1-file wont work together - and i dont see why (maybe im too much into detail already to miss something obvious). The only output created in the new csv-file is the BOM (its only 1 kb big).

Comment: `Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $element` -> `Get-ADGroupMember`? What is `Get-ADGroup $element -Properties managedby | Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $element` supposed to accomplish anyway?

Comment: honestly i'm pretty new to powershell and i'm doing learning on the fly - looking up snippets and getting info from ps get-help. what i'm trying to achieve i already posted in the question above.

Comment: After playing with your script and example, I only got it to work when I added the headers into the import-csv.     Import-Csv -Delimiter ";" -Header Pfad,Ordnerebene,Berechtigungsgruppe_Domaene,Berechtigungsgruppe,Rechteart,Recht -Path $dateipfad

Comment: @yaquaholic: thx for the effort, but it still no value from the variable $g in the 1st part is given to the array in the 2nd part of the script

Comment: *Version 2* - The next problem is that Get-ADGroup command is only being populated with the last $g, not all of them, as it's populated after the foreach loop.  Try declaring a new array before you import-CSV with *$names = @()* then adding *$names +=  '*' + $d + '*'* within the first ForEach loop, then do a *ForEach ($name in $name { Get-ADGroup etc etc etc }*.

Comment: I also had to define *$Liste = @()*, to get it working fully.

Comment: thx, with $liste i actually had no problem at all - when i start part2+3 (array on a manually entered group + export) without part1 (import) it already works fine. what i still have to figure out is, how i can get the managedby from the group working into export

Comment: long speech shortened: since all 3 parts alone for them selve work, i divided them again (luckily i havent that many ad-groups to scoure, ~10-15)